# Tableau Pivot Rows into Columns

Tags: tableau-api

I have a table structure like this:

```
Department   Employee  Class Peroid   Qty1 Qty2 Qty3
----------------------------------------------------
Dept1        John        1     1st    1    2    3
Dept1        John        1     2nd    11   22   33
Dept1        Mary        1     1st    2    3    4
Dept1        Mary        1     2nd    22   33   44
Dept2        Joe         1     1st    3    4    5
Dept2        Joe         1     2nd    33   44   55
Dept2        Paul        1     1st    4    5    6
Dept2        Paul        1     2nd    44   55   66
```

In a view I'd like to display the format as such:

```
                           Class  /  Period
                                  1
Department    Employee      1st       2nd
----------------------------------------------
Dept1         John         1  2  3   11 22 33
Dept1         Mary         2  3  4   22 33 44
Dept2         Joe          3  4  5   33 44 55
Dept2         Paul         4  5  6   44 55 66
```

I can't seem to find a way to do this. I have Class, Period as Columns and Department, Employee as Rows then drag Qty1, Qty2, Qty3 to the Text Mark but the format becomes:

```
                           Class  /  Period
                                  1
Department    Employee      1st       2nd
----------------------------------------------
Dept1         John          1         11
                            2         22
                            3         33   
Dept1         Mary          2         22 
                            3         33
                            4         44 
Dept2         Joe           3         33 
                            4         44
                            5         55  
Dept2         Paul          4         44
                            5         55
                            6         66
```

How do I turn those rows under each employee to sub-columns under Period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to achieve.

[image]

Comment: Bernardo, yes, this looks exactly what I'm trying to do. Since I'm fairly new to Tableau, could you explain how you did it in steps? Thanks.

Comment: here's the workbook. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60455118/160223%20stack%20question.twbx

Comment: It's pretty straight forward. start adding your columns and rows in the manner you need. Add Measure Values to the Text pill and Measure names to the Columns pill. In the Measure Values box, remove the items not Qty1,2,3 so it only displays what is needed.

Comment: Thanks. I got it now. If you don't mind, one more question, how do I do sub and grand totals on this workbook? I tried right-clicking on either Employee or Department but I don't see the "subtotals" menu option on Employee and it's greyed out on Department.

Comment: Go Analysis > Totals > Add all subtotals.

Comment: Nice! Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of times when you see a repeating column in a database table, Qty1, Qty2, Qty3, it is a sign that you really want multiple rows each with a single Qty (and repeating the other information) -- At least when you are building reports. That way you can have rows with any number of instances of Qty, and you can also easily aggregate all the Qty together when needed.

There are situations where you may want to stick with a repeating field design. But if you do want to reshape the data, you can do that in Tableau's data connection window by selecting the columns you want to pull out into a single field and selecting the pivot command.

Comment: Alex, thanks for the suggestions and information. Very helpful.